# JPQL bind parameter to ID

Tags: hibernate, jpa

I have a seemly silly question here.

I have a CardUser entity and a Card entity where each Card belong to one CardUser and CardUser can have more than one Card, all simple 1-to-many relationship.

Then I have a query to find out what is the User of a given Card:

```
select c from CardUser c left join c.cards cc where cc = ?1
```

and I have a method to call the query:

```
public CardUser findUserByCard(Long cardId);
```

My Question is then:

Do I have to bind the ?1 to a Card instance? It just looks silly in the implementation that I have to get the Card instance first with the cardId, and then bind it in the query. It is a double trip to the database and in the end, the database is really only taking the cardId anyway.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you must bind the parameter to a Card instance. But there are other ways to solve the problem:

1. Rewrite the query as

   ```
   select c from CardUser c left join c.cards cc where cc.id = :cardId
   ```
2. Leave the query as is, but use `EntityManager.getReference()` instead of using `EntityManager.find()` to get the card with this ID. `getReference()` returns an uninitialized proxy, and doesn't query the database.
3. Don't write any query, and use

   ```
   Card card = em.find(Card.class, cardId);
   CardUser user = card.getUser();
   ```